# Uno Flip - What color do you play when a person flips?

Tags: uno, uno-flip

I just bought a new Uno called [Uno-Flip](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/271460/uno-flip) and in this game, we have a Light Side and a Dark Side. When we use one of the `Flip Cards`, we have to (according to rulebook)

> When you play this card, everything flips from the Light Side to the Dark Side (or vice versa). Once the Flip card has been played, flip over the Discard Pile (the card just played will now be on the bottom), then the Draw Pile, then everyone's hands must flip to the other side. This new side will remain in play until another Flip card is played, changing it again. This card may only be played on a matching color or on another Flip Card.

Think of this scenario, when we start the game, we put a card in the Discard Pile from the Draw Pile. On the dark side of this card (light side starts face-up) it is a `teal 5`.
After a couple of rounds someone plays the Flip Card. We flip the Discard Pile and the `teal 5` on the dark side is face up.

**My Question**

What should our next card be based on?
The `teal 5` or the `yellow Flip Card`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/GDR44-English.pdf

> Whether playing the Light Side or the Dark Side, on your turn, you must match a card from your hand to the card on the top of the DISCARD pile, either by number, color or symbol (symbols represent Action Cards; see FUNCTIONS OF ACTION CARDS).

The `teal 5` is on top of the DISCARD pile, therefore the next play should be on the `teal 5`.

Comment: Wow, I musst have been thinking too hard to think simple... :D